# How to convert GTK keyboard event keys to English in any language layouts?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, keyboard-events, keyboard-layout

I want to use keyboard shortcuts (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and etc.) in my GTK-3 app. I get different keyboard events for different keyboard layouts.
For example my keyboard have English and Russian layouts and so my Russian key "Я" is at "Z".
There are many languages in world. How I can make app which works with any languages?

Now I translate keycodes only for Russian keyboard this way:

```
func main_event_listener(event *gdk.Event){
    eventObject := &gdk.EventKey{event}
    key := eventObject.KeyVal()
    state := eventObject.State()
    key, state = GTK_TranslateKeyLayoutEnglish(key, state)
    if state == gdk.GDK_CONTROL_MASK {
        if key == gdk.KEY_z {
            //Ctrl+Z
        } 
        if key == gdk.KEY_c {
            //Ctrl+C
        }
        if key == gdk.KEY_v {
            //Ctrl+V
        }
    } else {
        if key == gdk.KEY_F5 {
            //F5
        }
        if key == gdk.KEY_Delete {
            //Delete
        }
    }
}

func GTK_TranslateKeyLayoutEnglish(key uint, state uint) (uint, uint) {
    key2 := key
    state2 := state
    if state2 > 8192 { //RUSSIAN Ctrl 8196 == English Ctrl 4
        state2 -= 8192
    }
    switch key {
    case gdk.KEY_Cyrillic_ya: //RUSSIAN 'я'
        key2 = gdk.KEY_z
    case gdk.KEY_Cyrillic_ef: //RUSSIAN 'ф'
        key2 = gdk.KEY_a
    case gdk.KEY_Cyrillic_che: //RUSSIAN 'ч'
        key2 = gdk.KEY_x
    case gdk.KEY_Cyrillic_es: //RUSSIAN 'с'
        key2 = gdk.KEY_c
    case gdk.KEY_Cyrillic_em: //RUSSIAN 'м'
        key2 = gdk.KEY_v
        //etc
    }
    return key2, state2
}
```

I expect better realization of GTK_TranslateKeyLayoutEnglish() function

Comment: Use [gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Keyboard-Handling.html#gdk-keymap-translate-keyboard-state).

Comment: Thank you. This look like what I need. But I can't find good examle of using this.